# How can i optimise this function (beginner ) JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, performance

I have this function and I need to optimise it so that it takes less time running:

```
public static int recherche(int cherche, int[] t) {
    int srch = 0;
    int tmp=0;
    boolean result = false;
    for (int i=0; i<t.length ; i++) {
        if (t[i]== cherche && result == false) {
            tmp++;
            srch = i;
            result=true;
        }
    }       
    if (tmp!=0) { 
        return srch ;
    }
    else { 
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Also I can't use any library tools.

Comment: Please add a description of what this program is trying to do, what the input is and what the expected results are. What makes you think it is taking too long? If you're simply looking for the first match then you want to break out of your for loop after finding a match.

Comment: yes , sorry for the lack of description , so this is searching for the index of the first occurrence of cherche in t, or returns -1 if not found . also this is a class exercise , and we are given a function that represents the time it takes in a graph .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your method correctly you are searching for the index of the first occurrence of `cherche` in your array `t`, or -1 if not found.

The problem with your code is, that you keep looping even if you already found the entry. It is better to break the loop immediately. You also do not need the extra variables.

```
public static int recherche(int cherche, int[] t) {
    int srch = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        if (t[i] == cherche) {
            srch = i;
            break;
        }
    }       
    return srch;
}
```

If this is still too slow, you could try to store the data sorted or create some kind of index.

If you had a List instead of an Array, you could use the [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) method, but I do not think it can be any faster for unsorted data.
It will be always `O(n)`, because you have to check all array values in the worst case.

P.S: Please consider to use better variable names. I have no idea what `t` and `cherche` are.

Comment: It appears "cherche" is French for "seek".

Comment: thanks for the help , breaking out when index is found reduced the time greatly  . also sorry for the variable names , first time in here .

Answer (score 1):

There is no real optimization that can be done with this function in Java. If you know that the array `t` is sorted, you could use binary sort.

I cleaned your code up a bit though

```
public static int recherche(int cherche, int[] t) {
    for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        if (t[i] == cherche) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The optimizations you can do are returning the result right after you found it and removing redundant variables.

```
public static int research(int searched, int[] t) {
    for (int i=0; i < t.length ; i++) {
        if (t[i] == searched) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```